# rails3-jquery-autocomplete: A way to display suggestion for either category or collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-autocomplete

I am using [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) for my search which is working fine for single column. I need a way to customize it, e.g:

I have two columns named:

- category
- collection

now both the category and collection will have some values that are repeating.

suppose,

**category = Aurora, Austin, Aurora, Barrie, Barrie, Austin, etc**

collection = Bedrooms, Upholestry, Bedrooms, Bedrooms, Dining Set, etc

Now, if user type **"Au"** in autocomplete search field, I want to display autocomplete result to **Aurora, Austin,** skipping duplicate values similarly if there are any collections that starts with "Au" I want to display them too.

for more clarity, If user types **"B"** in autocomplete search field, then the auto complete result should be **"Barrie" from category, "Bedrooms" from collection**  and it should skip all the duplication.

For now I am displaying from category field only with this override method and it is working fine for category. I don't know how to use multiple column in autocomplete search.

```
autocomplete :slide_show, :category

def autocomplete_slide_show_category
 render json: SlideShow.select("DISTINCT category as value").where("LOWER(category) like LOWER(?) ", "#{params[:term]}%")
end
```

so, how to fix this issue and customize the autocomplete search?

Answer (score 0):

Any way I have solved this but, any best solution will be appreciated

I have done something like :

```
autocomplete :slide_show, :category


def autocomplete_slide_show_category
 category = []
 collection = []
 result = []

 categories = SlideShow.where("manufacturer_id = ? AND category ILIKE ?", @manufacturer.manufacturer_id, "#{params[:term]}%")
 collections = SlideShow.where("manufacturer_id = ? AND collections ILIKE ?", @manufacturer.manufacturer_id, "#{params[:term]}%")

 # push slide_show category to category array
 categories.each do |result|
  category << result.category
 end

 # push slide_show collections to collection array
 collections.each do |result|
  collection << result.collections
 end

 # filter category or collection array to provide unique result
 result = category.uniq + collection.uniq

 # render the unique category or collection to display in auto complete suggestion
 render json: result
end
```